Pointer Arrays and Addresses
I am starting to work on the topic of pointer arrays. I have assembled a little Test-Code but i am frustrated since line 14 and 15 do not print the same value hence the address of student1[0]. The stored Value of the array_ptr should be the address of student1 but it isnt. Can someone explain?
Thx !
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *array_ptr[5] = {0};

    char student1[] = {"Peter"};

    printf("%p\n", array_ptr[0]);

    array_ptr[0] = student1;

    printf("Address stored in Pointer: %p\n", array_ptr);
    printf("Address Student: %p\n", &student1);

    printf("Value Pointer: %s\n", *array_ptr);
    printf("Value Student1: %s\n", student1);

    return 0;
}


The line     printf("Address stored in Pointer: %p\n", array_ptr); says to print the address of array_ptr. But what you really want to print is the contents of array_ptr[0], which is where you stored the address of  student1.

Strictly speaking, the argument for %p must have type void *.  In many implementations, any pointer type will work, but in some it may not.  To be strictly compliant, cast the printf pointer arguments to void *.

printf("Address stored in Pointer: %p\n", array_ptr);
This is the address of your array, not where the first item points. Should be *array_ptr or  array_ptr[0].

And should be cast to void * to pass to printf.
